# How to upload video with browse button in magento 2 admin?

Tags: requirejs, magento2

I have tried to place a browse button in add video section and i am unable to save that video.

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I am also having same problem. Could you some help on same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a plugin to handle your file ,then upload it to media folder and save url to that file to database

Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\HelperPlugin

```
 <?php
    namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization;

    use \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper;

    class HelperPlugin
    {
        protected $mediaDirectory;
        protected $objectManager;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $mediaDirectory,
            \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
        ) {
            $this->mediaDirectory = $mediaDirectory;
            $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        }

        public function afterInitialize(Helper $subject, $result)
        {
            if(!empty($_FILES['product']['name']['yourvideoatributename'])) {
                $uploader = $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader', ['fileId' => 'product[yourvideoatributename]']);
                $mediaDirectory = $this->mediaDirectory->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $wrapDir = uniqid();
                $fileName = $uploader->getCorrectFileName($_FILES['product']['name']['yourvideoatributename']);
                $saveResult = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('catalog/product/manual/' . $wrapDir), $fileName);
                $result['yourvideoatributename'] = 'catalog/product/yourvideoatributename/' . $wrapDir . '/' . $saveResult['file'];
            }

            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Vendor\ModuleName\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
<config>
    <type name="\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper">
        <plugin name="yourp-initialize-after" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\HelperPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score -1):

Upload Product Videos:

Step 1: Get Your YouTube API Key

Step 2: Configure Magento

Step 3: Link to the Video

Step 1: Get Your YouTube API Key

Log in to your Google account, and visit the Google Developers Console. Then, follow these:

Under Use Google APIs, click Youtube Data APIs.

In the panel on the left choose Credentials, click on Create Credentials and choose API key.

When prompted to create a new key, choose Server key. Enter a name for the key and IP address, and click on Create.

After you get the key, copy the key to the clipboard.

Step 2: Configure Magento

On the Admin Sidebar, Stores > Settings > Configuration.

In the panel, under Catalog, choose Catalog.

Expand the Product Videos section, paste Youtube API key into the required field.

How to upload Product Videos Add API key

Click Save Config.

Go to Cache Management to refresh the cache.

Step 3: Link to Video

From the Poduct Detail, click on Add Video in the Images and Videos.

Enter the URL of the YouTubeu or Vimeo video.

In the URL field, if you haven’t entered Youtube API key yet, the system error message will appear, click on OK to continue.

How to upload Product Videos Error Message

Enter the Title and Description of the video.

To upload a Preview Image, browse to the image and select the file.

If you prefer to use the video meta data, click on Get Video Information.

To assign the role to the video, mark the corresponding checkbox of each Role:

Base Image

Small Image

Swatch Image

Thumbnail

Hide from Product Page

When complete, click on Save.

Comment: thank you abhinav but i need to upload a video from my local machine.